# Why I obtain weird colors on the normal map?

Tags: baking, normal-map

I baked a normal map (from a high poly mesh to a low poly mesh)and I obtain weird colors. I obtain the same result using the Ray distance and using a cage.

[image]

When I put the high poly mesh and the low poly mesh on the same layer it looks like this (I selected the high poly and that wood end look is also from the high poly):

[image]

It looks the same on the bottom:

[image]

And the whole model:

[image]

I am refering to this areas:
(is something wrong or is just the margin):

[image]

Here is the uv map from the low poly mesh :
[image]

Comment: What is weird on the map? Also could you add a picture of the low poly UV map?

Comment: yes the colors look correct

Comment: on the uv map you can see that the ovals are surrounded by a weird color band .

Comment: @Krenk the color band is the margin around the uv isle. You can lower it if you want in the bake setting. The important point is the margin should not overlap another uv isle.

Comment: all the time I thought I was doing something wrong :))))) Thanks a lot!